# Using second monitor for dashboard while still being two separated monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, openstack, virtualdesktop

I am not sure if this question has been asked before.

Basically I have a second monitor that is currently connected to a raspberry pi. It shows a dashboard (website). Unfortunately the raspberry pi is too weak for the dashboard.

I am looking for a program that I can use so I can connect the second monitor to my PC using the HDMI port. My primary screen is connected with DisplayPort. Then show the dashboard on the second monitor but it runs on my PC instead of the pi.

They still have to be separated monitors though, so I should not be able to drag a window to the second screen or let my mouse pointer go to the second monitor. Basically exactly like now but instead running the dashboard on my, much more powerfull, PC.

Is this even possible? I was looking at virtual desktops but that does not seem my solution and I don't know where to look. Does someone as a suggestion or point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Linux Mint 20, so Ubuntu 20.04